# Gradle sync fails when trying to add firebase ml vision image label model

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-mlkit

Gradle sync fails when trying to add image label model or tensorflow with the following message:

```
Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-image-label-model:16.0.0  
Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-tensorflow:16.0.0
```

Anyone know why this is happening?

ML Vision for text extraction works fine:

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:16.0.0
```

Using AS 3.2 Canary 15 with android gradle plugin 3.2.0-alpha15 and google play services version 3.2.1.

Comment: Thanks for the question! And thanks @MohammadAli for answering. FYI the official documentation is fixed now.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the quick turnaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your library with below library:

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-image-label-model:15.0.0
```

[Firebase Android Release Notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android)

Comment: They should update the [Label Images docs.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/label-images)

Comment: refer also this [Link](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mlkit-android/#3) and  read **`build.gradle`**

Comment: Thanks. I will put in an internal ticket to fix the Label Images docs.

Comment: And.. it should be fixed now! https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/label-images. Thanks for pointing it out.